# Derivative of ReLu function

Tags: derivatives

According to this wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function

the derivative of the Rectified linear unit (ReLU) function:

$$f(x) = 0 \text{ if }x<0; x \text{ otherwise }$$

has a value of $f'(0)=1$. This surprise me, because on this point I expected undefined derivate or something similar to delta Dirac (compare with the "binary step" function of same page).

Could someone explain why derivative is 1 and not undefined ?

Comment: The ReLU function $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, and the Wikipedia article is incorrect to state that $f'(x) = 1$ when $x = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $$f(x) = 0 \text{ if }x<0; x \text{ otherwise }$$

at $x=0$ we have the  right derivative $ f'_+(0) = 1$ and the left derivative $ f'_-(0) = 0$

Thus $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Editorial: last statement refers to f'(0) not f'(1).

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Thanks, fixed it .

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, you are right; that derivative is undefined. However, in practice, when coding, you *need* to give it a value so that the program doesn't crash if it should happen to stumble upon $f'(0)$ during calculations. If you have to choose a number, then either $0$ or $1$ would be most natural to pick (since those are the left and right derivatives at $0$), and so, either by random chance or because it actually works better, $f'(0) = 1$ has been picked as a convention.

Comment: Main use of this derivative is in the iterative algorithm to find the local minimum, $x_{i+1}=x_i-\lambda ~ f'(x_i)$, and taken into account that at x=0 we are at the minimum, the best option could be f'(0)=0.

Comment: @pabasaporaqui What is the best option really needs to be _tested and benchmarked_. It's possible that the involved if-tests work faster for $f'(0)=1$, or any of a myriad of other effects. Or there is no difference, and they just picked one. Also, minimisation of error does not correspond to minimisation of vertex output.